# How to fetch cell values from gridview

Tags: c#

I am trying to retrieve the values of the below template field but getting an empty string.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Payment Amount">

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CurrencyCode")%>

                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "InvoiceAmount")%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

The code that i am using to fetch it is,

```
dr["CurrencyCode"] = row.Cells[7].Text.Substring(0,2);
                    dr["InvoiceAmount"] = row.Cells[8].Text.Substring(3, row.Cells[7].Text.Length - 1);
```